# Stop all Flow Servers

Tags: flowtype

Sometimes it seems like Flow isn't working right and `flow stop; flow start` seems to fix the problem. Is there a command to stop (or restart) all Flow servers? like `flow stop --all`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is no such command that is part of Flow, but I sometimes use `killall flow` for this purpose. It works on OS X and Linux.